# exception is: Message: chrome not reachable, while using Selenium python to launch url

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-chromedriver

I am aware of multiple instances of similar question and I have tried to do all solutions proposed but still get the same error. Below is the code:

```
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument('--disable-infobars')
    options.binary_location = r"C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe"
    options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    options.add_argument('--remote-debugging-port=9222')
    options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
    options.add_argument('--disable-web-security')
    options.add_argument('--disable-webgl')
    options.add_argument('--disable-popup-blocking')
    #options.add_argument('--headless')
    options.add_argument('--disable-setuid-sandbox')
    options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
    options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
    options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
    options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
    options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
    options.add_argument(f"--user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\user1\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default")
    options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
    #pdb.set_trace()
    #service = Service(r'C:\\Data\\installs\\chromedriver.exe')
    #service.start()
    #print(service.service_url)
    #pdb.set_trace()
    #driver = webdriver.Remote(service.service_url,options=options)
    #driver.implicitly_wait(10)
   driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)
    driver.get("https://www.google.com")
    print("Chrome Driver Loaded")
```

Exception:

```
exception is: Message: chrome not reachable
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
Ordinal0 \[0x0042ACD3+2075859\]
Ordinal0 \[0x003BEE61+1633889\]
Ordinal0 \[0x002BB680+571008\]
Ordinal0 \[0x002B12EA+529130\]
```

PS: I am running above code from eclipse (F9). A chrome window is launched but with empty url.
What am I missing, or how I can I debug it better?

[image]

```
Google Chrome   107.0.5304.88 (Official Build) (64-bit) (cohort: Stable)
Chromedriver: 107.0.5304.62
```

Comment: The page loads `https://www.google.com`, which is what you requested.

Comment: Thank you for comment, it seems for me there shall be something in security layer for my organization that is preventing this. I will figure it out with IT support.